# Hardware and software to check mainboard controllers on flaws

Tags: motherboard, software-rec, hardware-rec

I'm looking for hardware and software which can indicate what is wrong with a computer. I repair computers myself, but often a problem takes to much time because you have to figure out the source of the problem. Does anyone here know good hardware/software tools to test hardware.

I found this one too, but this one is pretty expensive

http://www.pcdservicecenter.com/

edit: please dont close this thread for duplicated reasons, my question is about a bag of hardware testing tools for non working pc's. ie: pci port tester, agp tester, northbridge tester etc etc, not for a unbuntu live cd with some other troubleshooting software

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, half of those tools are a load of over priced rubbish.

When I last looked a few years ago, you can pick up PCI and similar diagnostic cards from eBay for around £5.

Nothing beats experience and usually these tools are only as good as the computer they are run on - serious problems don't always show up.

If a problem takes too much time, you need to charge more or work out why it is taking long - but there is no miracle item you can plug in and just find out what is wrong.

Comment: it would be nice though. For that price, i wouldn't even consider it.

Comment: For £5?! Lol. Learn to charge per hour. Long cases take longer, cost more.